# Increse number on click in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to create a scoring system. So if the user clicks numbers, player 1 gets 1 point and if they click letter player 2 gets 1 point

```
import pygame
import pygame.freetype
import random

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)  # Fullscreen
```

Here I have created a variable to store number and changed it to display on screen.

```
number = 0
str_number = str(number)

def text():
game_font = pygame.freetype.SysFont("monospace", 45)
text_surface, rect = game_font.render(str_number, (0, 0, 0))
screen.blit(text_surface, (250, 700))

game_font = pygame.freetype.SysFont("monospace", 45)
text_surface, rect = game_font.render(str_number, (0, 0, 0))
screen.blit(text_surface, (1300, 700))
```

In my main loop, I tried to increase the number by one whenever the user press the key. but it is not working.

```
running = True
while running:
screen.fill((255, 194, 102))  # RGB

    for event in pygame.event.get():  # Event handler
    ...

      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_1 or event.key == pygame.K_b and len(cards) > 0:
            cards.pop(0)
            number += 1
        if event.key == pygame.K_2 or event.key == pygame.K_n and len(cards) > 1:
            cards.pop(1)
            number += 1
        if event.key == pygame.K_3 or event.key == pygame.K_m and len(cards) > 2:
            cards.pop(2)
            number += 1

text()
pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Please care about the formatting of your code. Please read [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rendered text does not magically change when you change the number. You have to re-render the text after increasing the number.

Do not create the `pygame.font.Font` object in every frame and do not render the text in every frame. Create the text *Surface* once at the begin of the program. Just `blit` the text *Surface* in every frame:

Simplify the code with functions. e.g.:

```py
game_font = pygame.freetype.SysFont("monospace", 45)
text_surface, rect = game_font.render(str(number), (0, 0, 0))

def text():
    screen.blit(text_surface, (250, 700))
```

```py
def increment_score():
    global number
    number += 1
    return game_font.render(str(number), (0, 0, 0))
```

```py
while running:
    # [...]

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # [...]

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_1 or event.key == pygame.K_b and len(cards) > 0:
                cards.pop(0)
                text_surface, rect = increment_score()

            if event.key == pygame.K_2 or event.key == pygame.K_n and len(cards) > 1:
                cards.pop(1)
                text_surface, rect = increment_score()

            if event.key == pygame.K_3 or event.key == pygame.K_m and len(cards) > 2:
                cards.pop(2)
                text_surface, rect = increment_score()
```